# Model folder is not available in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

In laravel 5.3 there is no model available. Is it safe to work without model and write all the query in controller or how to work with it. 
Please anyone help me out for this

Answer (score 0):

You simply place your models in the `app` folder, in fact laravel will do this for you if you run:

`php artisan make:model MyModel`

It then gets namespaced to `App`. You should already have the `User` model in your App folder, which you can look at now you know where to find it. You don't need to (and shouldn't) put everything inside your controllers.